# Create a Log with the modifications in the DB

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have a Winforms App that uses a database to save the data in. I need to create a mechanism that gives me the possibility  to create a "log-like" file with the date of modification of one table and, in some cases, i need the date and what was modified in the row.
Can anyone give me some help in this?
Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't remember the exact mechanism off the top of my head.  If you are using EF, in the Save method you can acess the ChangeManger(?) to determine which entities have been aadde/modified/deleted, and post those changes to your changehistory.

Comment: what are you trying to say with "EF". newb here